# Assign timestamp as index with read_sql_table in Dask

Tags: python, sqlite, dask

In SQLite, I have a table `data` with index column `time` which is a timestamp generated at recording by `time.time()`

I want to load data from this table to a Dask DataFrame. For that I use :

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
data = dd.read_sql_table('data', 'sqlite:///'+DB_PATH, index_col='time', parse_dates={"time": {"unit":"s"}})
```

When i want to apply a rolling mean to the data `data.resample('15S').mean()`, I get :

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Float64Index'
```

So if I check the index by `data.index`, it gives me this, suggesting it's in the right dtype and that the `parse_dates` actually worked, right? :

```
Dask Index Structure:
npartitions=1
1.619876e+09    datetime64[ns]
1.620067e+09               ...
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
Dask Name: from-delayed, 3 tasks
```

Finally, I tried to defined the index datetime after loading:

```
data = dd.read_sql_table('data', 'sqlite:///'+DB_PATH, index_col='time')
data['time__1'] = pd.to_datetime(np.array(data['time__1']), unit='s') # By the way, I don't know why Dask creates a 'time__1' column...
data = data.set_index('time__1', sorted=True)
```

But then I get this message...

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with. It does not seem to be the most efficient since it does not take advantage of date_parse directly from `read_sql_table()` and rely on column `time__1` that was generated by Dask for a certain reason I don't know...

```
data = dd.read_sql_table('data', 'sqlite:///'+DB_PATH, index_col='time')
data = data.set_index(data['time__1'].map_partitions(pd.to_datetime, unit='s'))
data = data.drop('time__1', axis=1)
```

If you know a better solution...